# R system call returns error

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am trying to execute a python script from within R, with the following command:

```
system("python ~/speedtest-cli/speedtest-cli --simple")
```

The error I get is:

```
python: can't open file '/home/speedtest-cli/speedtest-cli': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The same command works just fine on the terminal. Am I using the command wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try subsetting `~` with your username.

Comment: tried that without luck.

Comment: What's the error messege for that? Is `/home/speedtest-cli/speedtest-cli` really the correct path of your script?

Comment: yes. The same command runs fine on the terminal.

Comment: Which command? with `~` or with `/home/speedtest-cli`? Did you try both?

Comment: I tried both. The `system()` function works fine for commands like `ls`, but throws me the aforementioned error when I try to run the command to run the python file.